# Error with Structure Listing entries

Tags: error, structure

```
EE: 2.7.1
Structure: 3.3.12
```

Here's what I'm doing when I get the error below:

1. Created a Template group `listings` and a template in that group called `contacts`.
2. Created a channel `contacts` with a few fields.
3. Went to Structure CP

   - Channel: Contacts
   - Type: Listing
   - Options: `listings/contacts`
4. Went to EE CP to create a new entry in the `contacts` channel.
5. Entered data into fields, then in the 'Structure' tab, I selected:

   - Structure Page URL: [autofilled from field entries]
   - Structure Template: `listings/contacts`
   - Listing Channel: [selected `Contacts`]

And we're getting this error:

[image: The error for Structure]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the latest version of EE and Structure.

Comment: If i ever figure out how to migrate my license from your site to devot-ee I'll be sure to try.